# Difference between DB::Table and DB::Select

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

At the moment I am using:

```
DB::select('select * from users ');
```

but now I'm reading on http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

about:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
```

Both give back the same. Is there something different between these two?

In the documentation it does say: `Note: The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding throughout to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.`

For the second method. Does this mean the first method doesn't protect you against SQL injection? Is the second method a better way? Both return the results in a different way as well right?

Can I get some explanation about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the only difference here is the syntax. Yes, a `DB::select` doesn't protect against SQL injection. But SQL injection is only a risk when you pass in user input. For example this is vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = "'.Input::get('name').'"');
```

Whereas this is not:

```
DB::table('users')->where('name', Input::get('name'))->get();
```

But also this isn't: (Using bindings "manually")

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?', array(Input::get('name')));
```

---

The great advantage of the query builder (besides automatically protecting against SQL injection) is it's flexible syntax. For example you could use a loop to add `where` statements:

```
$query = DB::table('users');

foreach($names as $name){
    $query->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', $name.'%');
}

$result = $query->get();
```

Comment: Since you've answered like all of my questions today. Can I ask you something else(not worth making a question about it) but maybe it's better to do so in a chat?

Comment: Sure you can invite to a chat on chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Wait how do I invite you exactly?

Comment: Lukas? Can you tell me how to invite you to a chat?

Comment: Go to my profile (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1903366/lukasgeiter) and click "start a room with this user" (or something like that)

Comment: ahhm.. with laravel 5.8.35 with postgresql 11, DB::select does protect from sql injection. it uses pdo and sends the named variables to the server. I personally don't like using a query builder.